# Idle remote ssh session slow to "wake up"

Tags: ssh

I have this minor, but annoying and puzzling issue:

- I `ssh` into an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop (from another Ubuntu machine)
- Login is fine, pretty fast
- I do whatever I do and leave the terminal idle for some time - say 10-20 minutes
- Then I return and type something ... now there is a significant delay - maybe 5 to 10 secs before anything happens
- But everything is normal after that again! No delays, nothing - all good and snappy again!

The remote machine is *not* going to sleep or hibernate or anything that I know of. It could even be crunching some long task. But this happens regardless of whether the machine is loaded or not, it seems.

Also, if there is any output printed to the terminal it never gets "drowsy", i.e. response is always fast.

Honestly, not sure if this has anything to do with Ubuntu or ssh. An ancient, Fedora PC sitting right next to it seems to not have any such issues.

Any ideas why this strange one-off delay happens and how to diagnose it? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect there is a router between you and your remote host, the router may try to close your idle connection, you can try to play with the "ServerAliveInterval" and "ServerAliveCountMax" in you ssh_config file.

Comment: Well, this happens on my home network between peer machines, on the same network. No router in the path.
But you have a point - I should mess with the ssh/sshd config files some, I have just been lazy :-)

Comment: FWIW, enabling `ServerAliveInterval`, i.e. setting it to non-zero, seems to create enough traffic to negate the problem. Which does not fully explain why it was happening in the first place, but fine.